# Converting Yolov4 Tiny to tflite. error:cannot reshape array of size 372388 into shape (256,256,3,3)

Tags: tensorflow, yolov4

i'm converting my custom weights file to tflite by using open source from https://github.com/haroonshakeel/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite.

there is no error when i convert Yolov4.weights to tflite but when i switch to Yolov4-tiny.weights i got an error like this

```
 conv_weights = conv_weights.reshape(conv_shape).transpose([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 372388 into shape (256,256,3,3)`

does anyone knows how to fix this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it doing 2 changes; replacing classes names and installing specific version of tensorflow-cpu (2.3.0)

1. In my case I changed the `core/config.py` file at the line 14 containing the code:

> __C.YOLO.CLASSES              = "./data/classes/coco.names"

replacing coco.names to custom.names, like that

> __C.YOLO.CLASSES              = "./data/classes/custom.names"

and then I created this new file `custom.names` at `./data/classes` directory
containing the names of my new custom classes instead of the default COCO classes.

2. I updated my pip3 version
   and then installed tensorflow version 2.3.0rc2 for cpu:

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

`pip3 install tensorflow-cpu==2.3.0rc2`

that solved the issue for me.

PS: I built my model on colab using gpu (T4) but I was testing/using the model on my local machine
without gpu.